# React Reloading Page doesn't work on Server, but works on localhost

Tags: reactjs, react-router, client-server

I've been searching for answers to this problem, but haven't found a solution yet. Maybe its simply because I don't understand the other answers given here on stackoverflow

My situation:
I have a React application running with React Router v4. My Application is running under http://localhost:3000/myApp and for production under http://myserver/myApp

My problem:
Whenever I refresh the page on the localhost, everything works fine. I can copy paste URL's without any problem, all behaves perfectly. When I do so on the server, I get an error "Not Found" ...

What I think / What I've tried so far:
I think I don't fully understand the difference between clientside and serverside routing. I thought I do so, but somehow it doesn't make sense to me that it works on localhost, but not on the server.

So actually I'm not sure if the problem is the client/serverside thing, or if its because my application is not running in the root directory. The /myApp on localhost is simply done by adding a `<BrowserRouter basename='/console'>` 
Could this be a problem? That the server is not able to interpret that correctly? Since the Server is an apache server with a lot of configs behind I don't really understand (its a business server, where other applications are hosted....).

I really think the problem is that I haven't implemented serverside routing yet... but why does it work on my localhost? Has webpack dev server implemented that behind the scenes?

I would be really thankfull if someone can help me out here. If you need more informations, feel free to ask :)

Thank you very much

Comment: Has webpack dev server implemented that behind the scenes?, yes, from my understanding, in this case, you need to implement a Server to serve your routes correctly, maybe you wanna can have a Node.js/express server, it won't cost you much. but, can you give example Route component from your application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to have a server that handles redirects for browser history api. in dev mode, webpack-dev-server will do that for you but when you deploy it, you need to equally configure your web server.

eg in apache, redirect to index when request does not match a file via `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.html
```

for instance, in express, you can use middleware like https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-history-api-fallback to redirect.

nginx example

```
# Default server configuration
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name myserver.me;
  root /var/www/app;
  # Routes without file extension e.g. /user/1
  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
  # 404 if a file is requested (so the main app isn't served)
  location ~ ^.+\..+$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
  }
}
```

etc etc.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, we'll try it this afternoon ;)

Comment: I'm 100 % sure you've given the right answer to solve this problem. Sadly, we can't implement this solution on our server due to other problems. But it would work, we tested it on another system.
We're gonna use HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter now

Comment: Solves the react reload issue. No more 403 pages!